# Whatsapp-cloud-api fails to send messages

Tags: python, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying to send whatsapp message using the test tel. number, using this code:

```
from heyoo import WhatsApp
messenger = WhatsApp (token,phone_number_id=phone_id)
messenger.send_message ('Hello I am WhatsApp Cloud API', target_number)
```

It seems to send alright but the acctual test message is not recieved.
Any ideas?